# Apply a loop through all files wth similar pattern -for many pattern names in R

Tags: r, loops, pattern-matching

I have a set of .csv files that correspond to specific stations for different years. I would like to make a pattern that would seek for all files that are similar from the 10th character until .csv.
So far, I have the following:

```
files =list.files(pattern = ".csv")
files
[1] "data2011_AAST0100.csv"  "data2011_ADST0500.csv"  "data2011_AETR0100.csv" 
[2] "data2011_AIST0200.csv"  "data2011_AKST0200.csv"  "data2011_AMST0100.csv" 
[3] "data2012_AAST0100.csv"  "data2012_AETR0100.csv"  "data2012_AIST0200.csv" 
[4] "data2012_AMST0100.csv"  "data2012_ANST0100.csv"  "data2012_APST0300.csv" 
[5] "data2013_AAST0100.csv"  "data2013_AETR0100.csv"  "data2013_AIST0200.csv" 
[6] "data2013_AMST0100.csv"  "data2013_ANST0100.csv"  "data2013_APST0300.csv"
```

However, I would like to have something like this, which basically seeks for all similar pattern names after the 10th character.

```
files =list.files(pattern = "AAST")
files
[1] "data2011_AAST0100.csv" "data2012_AAST0100.csv" "data2013_AAST0100.csv"
```

My goal is to apply the following loop for all stations.

```
outfile = ""
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  tempData = read.csv(files[i], header = FALSE, sep="", na.strings=c(" "))
  colnames(tempData) = unlist(headers)
  df[is.na(tempData)] = NA
  outfile <- rbind(outfile, tempData)
}
```

Comment: It does work, but I have to type manually the name "AAST". I would like the pattern argument to search automatically for all similar names after the 10th character, so I can rbind all years for each station separately.

Comment: You can use `substring` if the length is always the same to get the patterns. Elsewhere use regular expressions to find the pattern

Comment: Please take the time to review answers to your question, feed-back comments and, or mark accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `pattern` argument in `list.files`, you can get all the file names by calling `list.files` and then filter them with `str_extract_all()` from the `tidyverse` package.

```
library(tidyverse)

# test <- list.files()
test <- c("data2011_AAST0100.csv", "data2011_ADST0500.csv", "data2011_AETR0100.csv", 
          "data2011_AIST0200.csv", "data2011_AKST0200.csv", "data2011_AMST0100.csv")

unique(unlist(str_extract_all(test, pattern = '(?<=\\_).{4}')))

[1] "AAST" "ADST" "AETR" "AIST" "AKST" "AMST"
```

This assumes that the names you want to extract are always 4 letters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, I am not able to pass it into the list.files command.

Comment: Just loop over the vector, either with a `for` loop or with `lapply`.